# 2 dimensional array in struct with threading in C

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, multidimensional-array

Hello. I need to write program which create N 2-dimensional arrays (N is our argv[1] and size of arrays are N-N) with random numbers and then create N threads. Every thread gets his own 2-dimensional array and sums the numbers from every line and returns the greatest value to main thread. Main thread returns the largest sum from every thread.
Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct arguments {
int N;
double *tab;
};

void *func(void* arguments)
{   
struct arguments *args = arguments; 
int i,j;
int N = args->N;
double number;
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{  
   for (j=0; j<N; j++)
   {
    printf("Number = %d ", args->tab);              
   }
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
return NULL;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
srand((int)time(NULL));
int N;
int i;
int j;
struct arguments args;
sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&N);
args.N = N;
double **tab;

tab = (double **)malloc(N * sizeof(double *));
args.tab = malloc(args.N*args.N*sizeof(double));
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
   tab[i]= (double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
}        
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{  
  for(j=0; j<N; j++)
    {               
        tab[i][j]= rand()%20+1;
        args.tab = rand()%20+1;           
    }     
  pthread_t ptr;
  if (pthread_create(&ptr, NULL, func, (void *)&args) !=0){
  printf("You can't create a thread");
  return -1;
  }
  pthread_join(ptr, NULL);
}      
return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to use those arrays to get data properly from struct. This code returns me only 2 random numbers (I should get 8 for N = 2) and the rest is the same like those 2 (4 same numbers for one thread and other 4 same numbers for second thread). I know why it is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You have multiple problems. Some the compiler should complain about (through warnings, read them!), some which are more subtle. For example when you pass `&args` to the threads you create, you pass the ***same*** pointer to ***all*** threads. You need to create an array of `argument` structures, one for each thread.

Comment: Why do you cast the `malloc` return value of type `void*`. You've shown that this is not necessary with `struct arguments *args = arguments; `

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So should i change this line: struct arguments args; into this: struct arguments *args, add args = malloc(sizeof(*args)); and change every line with e.g args.N = for args->N? @ harper I'm sorry but i don't know what are you trying to tell me. Which cast of the malloc are you talking about?

Comment: No you need an *array*. You create `N` threads, so you need an array of `N` structures.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameters were actually entered by the user.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `srand()` is expecting a `unsigned int` parameter, not a `int` parameter.

Comment: in a thread function, using: `return NULL;` will NEVER be executed because the prior call to `pthread_exit()` already exited the function.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Number = %d ", args->tab);`  the values are of type `double`, so the format specifier needs to be of type `double`, not of type `int`.

Comment: the question states what each thread is supposed to perform.  However, all the thread(s) is doing is printing the contents of the passed in array.

Comment: regarding: `pthread_join(ptr, NULL);`  This statement is inside the loop that is creating the threads.  Therefore, each thread will be created, executed, and exited before the next thread is even thought about.  Suggest implementing an array of `thread_t` that contains `N` entries, then after the loop that creates the threads, in a loop, call `pthread_join()` for each entry in the new array.

Comment: regarding: ` if (pthread_create(&ptr, NULL, func, (void *)&args) !=0)
        {
            printf("You can't create a thread");
            return -1;
        }`   the code should not execute the `return -1;`  because that would result in the threads all being abruptly exited.  much better to set the current offset in the array of `pthread_t` entries to 0 then when calling `pthread_join()`, skip entries that contain 0

Comment: the posted code doesn't perform any collection (in main) of the values to be calculated in the threads, not display the largest value

Comment: regarding: `args.tab = rand()%20+1;`  this is trying to change where the `tab` field of the struct `args` is pointing.  That is not correct.  Suggest: `args.tab[ i ][ j ] = rand()%20+1;`  regarding this expression: `rand()%20+1`   due to the C operator precedence, this becomes: `rand()%21`  which is not what you want.  suggest: `(rand()%20) +1`

Comment: why have the local instance of `double tab[][]` in main.  That is not used for anything and just clutters the code.   Also, since the values in the struct 'args' will be updated for each pass through the loop (in main), the values seen by the thread function can be changed.  Suggest placing: `struct arguments args;` after the input of `N` and writing it like so: `struct arguments args[N];`

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  I.E. remove the statement: `#include <math.h>`